# How to add up the returns of str.count?

Tags: python

As the title says, I'm trying to add up the returns of str.count in my function. But i keep getting zero. advice needed.

```
def count_code(str):
  for i in range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1):
    new = str.count("co"+chr(i)+"e")
    count = int(new)+ int(new)
  print(count)

count_code('aaacodebbb')
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you keep getting zero is because you use a new `count` each time in the loop.

Try this:

```
def count_code(str):
    count = 0
    for i in range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1):
        new = str.count("co"+chr(i)+"e")
        count += int(new)
    print(count)

count_code('aaacodebbb')
```

Comment: Obvious! Thanks a lot!